# FB Share this link doesn't fetch post desc and thumb

Tags: facebook, wordpress, sharethis

On a wordpress site, I'm using sharethis plugin...

http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/446440-wordpress-integration

Where FB Share Link Button doesn't fetch and display Post description & image on facebook.

Any idea/hint what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add this function into your functions.php file.

```
function wpc_fb_opengraph() {
$wpc_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID HERE">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR FB USER ID (OR USERNAME) HERE"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $wpc_image_url[0] ?>"/>
<?php }

add_action('wp_head', 'wpc_fb_opengraph');
```

Note : if you haven't yet any facebook app for your web pages you dont have to use this lines .

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP ID HERE">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR FB USER ID (OR USERNAME) HERE"/>
```

Happy Wordpress..

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.. I just verified, I have this coming from the Yoast SEO Plugin, but still it doesn't work any idea?

Comment: Does Yoast SEO add any meta field results for your posts/pages meta desription/keyword area ?

Comment: Yes it adds meta data for each posts. However, when I pass direct URL it does work but... with share this plugin short url, it doesn't work.

Comment: technically this is correct answer... so marking it as selected answer... however this doesn't solve my problem. Marking it just to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try implemented the Open Graph Meta Tags if you haven't - the will give Facebook's servers hints as to what content you want to display if it can't be parsed automatically.

Info here: http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags